# Use do loop index in macro variable definition

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I would like to define multiple macro variables in a data step. In this case I would like to create the variables `&buffer1, &buffer2, &buffer3, &buffer4`.
The number of buffers is variable, so I am not able to hard code the creation of these variables.

Here is the data step and do loop I am currently using:

```
%let buffers = 4;
data buffer;
    do buffer_number = 1 to &buffers;
        buffer_queue = 0;
        buffer_index = 0;
        output;
    end;
run;
```

What I would like to do is add a line within the do loop like `%let buffer_buffer_number = 0;`. This obviously doesn't work, since it just creates the variable `&buffer_buffer_number`.Is there some way I can use the do loop index (buffer_number) to create the macro variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the `call symput()` subroutine.

```
call symput(catt("buffer_",buffer_number),0);
```

The first argument takes a string that contains the macro variable name.  Here I use the CATT() function to concatenate the values into the string you want.

The second argument is the value to put into the macro variable.

Comment: Use the newer `call symputx()` as it has more options and handles automatic conversion of numeric variables.